# Find and Replace special chracters in a string

Tags: php, string

I have to split each word and compare it with in-built local dictionary and replace it with the equivalent word in another language.When I split a words with special characters (**eg:**of!) it will not match with dictionary even if they are the same.

Now I need to replace those special characters by empty strings.

```
$opis="of!";
$a=preg_replace('!"#$%&/()=?*+'-.,;:_', '', $opis);
print_r($a);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `str_replace` or `preg_replace`

Example `preg_replace` http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

```
  $str = preg_replace("/\W+/", '', $str);
  var_dump($str);
```

Example `str_replace`  http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

```
$search =  '!"#$%&/()=?*+\'-.,;:_' ;
$search = str_split($search);
$str = "OF!" ;

var_dump(str_replace($search, "", $str));
```

Output

```
string 'OF' (length=2)
```

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong with everyone posting about Regular Expressions here? :/

Okay, the problems you're having with your current solution lie in how you've written your regular expression.

Step 1: Escape all of RegEx's internal special characters with a single `\` (as well as the extra single quote you left in your string...)

Result:

```
'!"#\$%&/\(\)=\?\*\+\'-\.,;:_'
```

Step 2: Encapsulate the result in a character class, otherwise RegEx will just try to replace all occurrences of the string `!"#$%&/()=?*+'-.,;:_`

Which is obviously not what you want to happen.

After encapsulation:

```
'[!"#\$%&/\(\)=\?\*\+\'-\.,;:_]'
```

Lastly, you need to delimit the regular expression with something (PHP requires this to define a regular expression), and we'll also add the greedy "+" sign to match as many sequential symbols as possible.

Final:

```
'~[!"#\$%&/\(\)=\?\*\+\'-\.,;:_]+~'
```

Now you should be good to go:

```
$opis="of!";
$opis = preg_replace('[!"#\$%&/\(\)=\?\*\+\'-\.,;:_]+', '', $opis);
print_r($opis)
```

Enjoy. Next time consult the best place for Regular Expression information [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info)

Answer (score 0):

is it what you are looking for?

http://php.net/manual/fr/function.str-replace.php

```
$result = str_replace($search, $replace, $subject);
```

Comment: I have many special characters !"#$%&/()=?*+'-.,;:_ to compare..through str_replace we can able to use only one special char to compare na?

Answer (score 0):

Use this regular expression for the above

```
$a=preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/", '', $opis);
```

Tested

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have when using Regular Expressions is that you need to escape several of the characters in the string, because Regular Expressions are using a multitude of special characters. A list can be found here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

Using a function like str_replace would be an easier solution.

Answer (score 0):

[str_replace();](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) is what you need.

from php official documentation:

```
// Provides: Hll Wrld f PHP
$vowels = array("a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U");
$onlyconsonants = str_replace($vowels, "", "Hello World of PHP");
```

Answer (score 0):

how about using str_replace! it has smaller hit on the performance

```
$chars= array("!", "\"", "#", "$", "%", "&", "/", "(", ")", "?", "*", "+", "'", "-", ".", ",", ";", ":", "_");
$cleanstring = str_replace($chars, "", $yourstring);
```